# How to get bound data by using Container?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

It is understood that if you wish to get a container from an item in a ListBox you can use:

```
ListBoxItem lbi1 = (ListBoxItem)(listBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(0));
```

(Source: http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=7)

Assuming the above listbox was bound to a List, how can I do the opposite? As in, what if I wanted to get the databound data in the list by using the container (`lbi1` in the above example)?

Comment: Ok I think I have found the answer :)

For ListBox items or other similar ContentControls the data can be retrieved by something like:

    Class data = (Class)lbi1.Content;

For other controls, like TreeViewItems, as they are not ContentControls, the data can be retrieved by accessing the DataContext:

    Class data = (Class)treeViewItem.DataContext;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I think I have found the answer :)

For ListBox items or other similar ContentControls the data can be retrieved by something like:

```
Class data = (Class)lbi1.Content;
```

For other controls, like TreeViewItems, as they are not ContentControls, the data can be retrieved by accessing the DataContext:

```
Class data = (Class)treeViewItem.DataContext;
```